# Python class object has no attribute in a for loop

Tags: python, montecarlo

I have a Monte Carlo simulation where I am trying to randomize my Dryden wind model class with each iteration. Initializing the class works as expected for the first iteration; however, future iterations have the error "AttributeError: 'dryden' object has no attribute 'dryden'."

I am using this basic code structure, with the working aspects omitted. I don't believe the normal distribution of the velocity is an issue, as I get the same error with only the constant value too.

```
for j in tqdm(range(0, iterations)):
# Dryden initialization
    dryden_init = 1
    dryden_scale = 2

    if dryden_init == 1:
        dryden = dryden.dryden(np.random.normal(initlibrary.UAV_0["u0"], 5), alt0, dur, dt)
        y1_f, y2_f, y3_f = dryden.dryden_wind_velocities()
```

Inside the 'dryden' class, I have an initialization that is usually called with 'dryden.dryden' seen above. I think this is the part that is not working.

```
class dryden:
    def __init__(self, Vgps, alt_ref, dur, dt):
        self.Vgps = Vgps
        self.alt_ref = alt_ref
        self.dur = dur
        self.dt = dt
```

I am a newer Python user and couldn't find anything online related to this issue, but I don't know what to search. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: When you do `dryden = dryden.dryden()` in the first iteration of the loop then the second iteration the definition of `dryden` has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line

```
dryden = dryden.dryden(...
```

You change `dryden` from the class type you originally imported to instead an *instance* of that class. Instead pick a unique name for the variable in this loop

```
dryden_instance = dryden.dryden(np.random.normal(initlibrary.UAV_0["u0"], 5), alt0, dur, dt)
y1_f, y2_f, y3_f = dryden_instance.dryden_wind_velocities()
```